# socket hang up in tls node.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, tls1.2

I want to convert below python code to Node.js

```
    xmppSocket = socket.socket()
    xmppSocket.connect((HOST, 5222))
    xmppSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(xmppSocket)
    xmppSocket.sendall("Dummy Text")
```

So I wrote below code do the same.

```
var tls = require('tls');

   const options = {
      host: HOST,
      port: PORT
   };

    var socket = tls.connect(options, () => {
        console.log('client connected',
        socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');
}).setEncoding('utf8')
.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
})
.on('end', () => {
    console.log("End connection");
}).on('error', (error) => {
    console.log("Error is:", error)
});
```

But this is returning me below error.

```
Error: socket hang up
at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1092:19)
```

What exactly going wrong in this piece of code?
Why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Is the host and port correct?

Comment: Yes. When I use normal socket connection, it works well. When I switched to TLs `Error: socket hang up` is coming.

Comment: Add `.on('error', ...)` handler to socket as well. There are numerous reasons for hang up. My guess is that cipher is not supported or connection is just blocked.

Comment: @Artem Added error block. Still same error

Comment: Is this a self signed certificate? `rejectUnauthorized:false ` should set to in options?

Comment: also log error.code

Comment: @JingshaoChen Errorcode is `ECONNRESET`

Comment: Just to make sure, you changed port after switching to TLS, right?

Comment: @Artem I'm not changing the port. Using the same port 5222.

Comment: In Wireshark packet capture, I noticed that before establishing the connection it's sending the stream which is not happening in the python script.

Comment: Then probably ciphers not supported. Try different version of node.js, enable NODE_DEBUG (http://www.juliengilli.com/2013/05/26/Using-Node.js-NODE_DEBUG-for-fun-and-profit/)

Comment: Using Node 7.7.2